Weird behaviour when passing array to method in C
I wrote a method that takes as parameters two stations and an array of railway trails.
typedef enum { MA1, MA2, MA3, MA4, MA5, MA6, MA7, 
    MA8, MA9, MA10, MA11, MA12, MA13, MA14, MA15, MA16} RailwayTrack;

typedef enum { S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6} RailwayStation;

typedef struct TrainData {
    int currentProgress;
    RailwayStation startStation;
    RailwayStation endStation;
    int railwayPathLength;
    RailwayTrack *railwayPath;
} TrainData;

#define MAP1_TRAIN_N1 getTrainData(S1, (RailwayTrack[]){ MA1, MA2, MA3, MA8 }, S6)

TrainData getTrainData(RailwayStation startStation, RailwayTrack railwayPath[] /*ERROR HERE?*/, RailwayStation endStation) { 
  TrainData trainData;
  trainData.startStation = startStation;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(railwayPath)/sizeof(RailwayTrack); i++)
  {
    printf("Eli: %d\n",railwayPath[i]);
  }
  //OUTPUT: Eli0, Eli1

  RailwayTrack test[] = { MA1, MA2, MA3, MA8 }; //TEST ARRAY CAUSE ABOVE IS NOT WORKING
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(RailwayTrack); i++)
  {
    printf("Eli: %d\n",test[i]);
  }
  //OUTPUT: Eli0, Eli1, Eli2, Eli3
  
  trainData.railwayPath = railwayPath;
  trainData.endStation = endStation;
  return trainData;
}

The problem is that the array given as parameter won't get print out completely but just until the first 2 elements. You can see that as parameter I am passing an array of 4 elements but in the Logs only the first 2 are visible.
I was finally able to understand thanks to some help that I needed to pass the size of the array as parameter too. Thanks everyone for the help.

You can't pass arrays to functions. What the compiler will do with the argument RailwayTrack railwayPath[] is to treat it as RailwayTrack *railwayPath. I.e. you will get a pointer to the first element of the array. And the size of a pointer (e.g. sizeof(railwayPath)) is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to. You need to pass the size (number of elements) as a separate argument. This should really have been covered by any decent beginners material (book, tutorial, class, etc.).

"won't get debug completely" -- what precisely do you mean? That said, are you aware that you're just passing a pointer to that function? That said, for illustration, it's usually best to extract a [mcve]. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

@Someprogrammerdude true, I managed to solve thanks to this, if you put it as answer I'll give you the solution.

sizeof(railwayPath) is giving you the size of pointer not array in C. You do not pass the array, only reference (pointer to it).
You need to pass size as a parameter:
TrainData getTrainData(RailwayStation startStation, RailwayTrack railwayPath[],
                       size_t railwayPathSize, RailwayStation endStation) { 

